# Azure authentication failed using python sdk

Tags: python, azure

I am new to azure and just stared learning, my aim is to get instance information using azure cli and python sdk, I am learning from official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-python

I am trying to authenticate and get container info but script is not working, I have followed step 1 and 2. please help and if there is any other easy way to learn inform me.

here is code that i am using

```
from os import getenv
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_auth_file
from azure.mgmt.containerinstance import ContainerInstanceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient


AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION = 'C:\\Users\\gsc-30310\\PycharmProjects\\Azure\\my.azureauth'
auth_file_path = getenv('AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION', None)
if auth_file_path is not None:
    print("Authenticating with Azure using credentials in file at {0}"
          .format(auth_file_path))

    aciclient = get_client_from_auth_file(ContainerInstanceManagementClient)
    resclient = get_client_from_auth_file(ResourceManagementClient)
else:
    print("\nFailed to authenticate to Azure. Have you set the"
          " AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION environment variable?\n")
```

Comment: Please post the error that is returned or any information that could help in debugging the issue.

Comment: i am not getting error, my if statement is not running so program goes to else statement.

Comment: What is the value of auth_file_path before the if statement? Set a breakpoint there, or print the value.

Comment: it contains None value

Comment: I stored path directly  like this `auth_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\gsc-30310\\PycharmProjects\\Azure\\my.azureauth'
` and now i am getting `KeyError: 'AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION'`

Comment: You need to add it as system variable. What OS do you use?

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: i am also using virtual env

Comment: To set it as system variable type in the command prompt: set AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION="you path to credentals file". But before this, make sure that you successfully generated your credentials file

Comment: i am getting `Unable to initialize device PRN
` when i print `AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION` after initialization through cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vikas. I followed the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-python) and set the `AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION`.

[image]

Then you need to restart your dev tool so that it could read your latest env value in new windows session. Otherwise,it will be always `none`.

Comment: hi thanks, could you tell me how to set environment variable in pycharm?

Comment: @VikasGautam You mean you set the env var in code? I tested above answer just in windows advanced system settings.

Comment: @VikasGautam Great!